# Goal "cobertura:instrument" in Cobertura Maven Plugin

Tags: java, code-coverage, instrumentation, cobertura, maven-cobertura-plugin

What might be some real use case to invoke `cobertura:instrument` goal from Cobertura Maven Plugin?

I know that it just instruments classes, but when it may be preferred over `cobertura:cobertura` or `cobertura:check`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goal can be needed for instance for integration tests. If I make a parallel with what I'm doing with [`qualinsight-mojo-cobertura-core`](https://github.com/QualInsight/qualinsight-mojo-cobertura) (an alternative mojo to `cobertura-maven-plugin`), having a separate goal for instrumentation allows you to plug other actions between code instrumentation and coverage report generation.

For instance, if you take [this `pom.xml` example](https://github.com/pawlakm/qualinsight-mojo-cobertura-example/blob/master/wartest-jetty9.3.x/pom.xml), you'll see that:

- `instrument-it` is done during the `package` phase (using `qualinsight-mojo-cobertura-core`),
- jetty server is lanched during `pre-integration-test` phase,
- `it-tests` are run during the `integration-test` phase,
- jetty server is stopped during the `post-integration-test` phase (that's when the `cobertura.ser` file is written to disk) then
- `report-it-coverage` is run during the `verify` phase.

Without having two separate goals for instrumentation and report generation, this would'nt be possible. Side note: `cobertura:cobertura` also *executes* tests, it's an *all in one* goal.